# Flask application memory leakage with sql alchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am processing a large http response content(1 million records) by streaming it.
After reading 10000 elements from the request I am calling a method to insert them into database and then continuing processing the response. I have noticed that the RAM usage is continuously increasing.
Below is the sample code. If I comment the db.session.add() part tried to add the data to temporary list the memory leak is not happening. So SQLAlchemy is not properly releasing the memory after insertion to database? Please suggest.

Sample Code.

```
for chunk in response.iter_content(2048):
    #decode chunk
    xyz_json_list = list()
    xyz_json = json.loads(chunk_string)
    xyz_json_list.append(xyz_json)
    if len(xyz_json_list) == 10000:
        add_elements_to_db(xyz_json_list)
        xyz_json_list = list()
    ...



func add_elements_to_db(xyz_list):
    for xyz in xyz_list:
       db.sesssion.add(create_object_from_json(xyz))
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.expunge_all()
    del xyz_list
    gc.collect()
```

After each call to add_elements_to_db memory is increasing exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

as of `v1.0.0`, `SQLAlchemy` supports [Bulk Opertions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/persistence_techniques.html#bulk-operations)

- `Session.bulk_save_objects()`
- `Session.bulk_insert_mappings()`
- `Session.bulk_update_mappings()`

```
s = Session()
objects = [
    User(name="u1"),
    User(name="u2"),
    User(name="u3")
]
s.bulk_save_objects(objects)
```

so you can make little bit changes in `add_elements_to_db()` function:

```
[..]

def add_elements_to_db(xyz_list):

    objects = []
   
    for xyz in xyz_list:
        objects.append(create_object_from_json(xyz))

    db.session.bulk_save_objects(objects)

[..]
```

just curious, why you are not using `Redis` for asynchronous tasks, you can delegate the execution of `add_elements_to_db()` function as an asynchronous task to `Redis` since it's a blocking task and notably slow and for sure you'll see a good performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried using bulk_save_objects but it didn't solve my issue of memory being not freed up after adding objects to database using SQLAlchemy. Also bulk_save_objects is taking more time than adding individual object and doing commit at the end. I was looking for why the objects after adding to session aren't garbage collected and memory freed. Its a one time activity so not worried about performance.